# Runtime error 3000 and Reserved Error (-3087) Access 2010 macro/VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using Access 2010, I have entry cells for a table that span 5 separate forms, and I have created command buttons on each form to navigate between them, filtering the next form for the ID on the current form. Four of the five command buttons work just fine to filter to the proper form, but the command buttons associated with one form feedback an error message reading:

> Reserved Error (-3087); there is no message for this error.

I have used both macros and VBA to navigate between the forms, using either `OpenForm` with a filter on the Where Condition or `DoCmd.OpenForm`. The Macro looks like:

```
Open Form
     Form Name "MyForm"
     View Form
     Filter name
     Where condition =="[ID]=" & [ID]
     Data mode
     Window mode Normal
Close Window
     Object Type Form
     Object Name "CurrentForm"
     Save No
```

And the VBA code looks like:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm _
  "MyForm" _
, acNormal, _
, "[ID] = " & [ID] _
, acFormEdit _
, acNormal
```

The VBA also feedback

> Runtime Error 3000.

Google searches and searches of stack overflow have yielded nothing helpful. This error seemingly arose for no reason, as the command buttons worked fine before. And all the other command buttons linking to the other forms work just fine.

I'm guessing that the issue stems from the destination form, not the macro or VBA, but I can't seem to figure out a problem with it. I've:

- enabled the database in the Trust Center
- tried using a `tempVar` to filter the form
- tried opening a blank form with an `OnLoad` event

(all of which result in the same error 3087)

Comment: There are way too many pieces to this puzzle to make an educated guess, so I suggest that you break this down to something simple. Please confirm that you get the error on the 'DoCmd.OpenForm'?  First I would manually open that form and make sure it works. Open your VBA Project and paste the following in the immediate window and execute it:
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & [ID], acFormEdit, acNormal   Based on the success or failure, then we can move to step 2.

Comment: At the risk of exposing myself as a VBA rookie, I've done this and recieved "Compile Error: External Name not defined". I am able to pull up the form from the objects panel, and access it from a navigation form that is apart from the data entry forms. However, when I select "toggle filter" in the home ribbon of the GUI it also gives the 3087 error.

Comment: Did you change 'MyForm' to be your form name? Rats, sorry I see... you don't have '[ID]' in this context. Just remove the filter and try again.

Comment: I did change the form name for the immediate window attempt. And I attempted the immediate window in absence of the filter (except as applied by the OpenForm). In fact, if I drop the "Where" clause out of the OpenForm command the command pulls up an unfiltered copy of the form.  As for the filter, I was trying it as another solution and hoping to narrow the issue down to problems with the filtering. I guess I wasn't precise enough in my previous comment. I did nothing else but pull up the desired form from the object panel and click to "toggle filter" button and it gave me the 3087 error.

Comment: If you were able to open as an unfiltered form from the immediate window, but it gives an error if you toggle the filter, I would: (1) open in design view and check Recordsource ... is it a table or a query? does it look ok? (2) Check the Filter property, FilterOn, Allow Filters, etc. and see if something is out of place from what it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I opened form in design view and it had a filter in the property sheet that appears to be from the VBA command that feeds back the error! It does not appear from the macro. I engage the command, get the error and pull up the form separately, with filter present. I can't toggle the filter with the GUI. I was able to open the form unfiltered from the immediate window. Recordsource is a query, and it looks fine except not explicitly containing the cell that I want to filter (just a * of the table). I corrected that. I still get the 3087.

Comment: I would try to: (1) Open the form in design view; (2) Delete the filter; (3) Save the form; (4) try your Macro and see if the form opens OK; So at this point, Step 4 is either 'Pass' or 'Fail'; (5) If it fails, copy the recordsource and execute manually -- with the proper filters; does that work ok? (6) Is there one method of opening that 'works' all the time?

Comment: Done through step 4 and still failing. Copied SQL code for query, created a new query and ran code, entering filter using WHERE clause (artificially because I could only enter a number, not a current value property for cell in a form I'm navigating from). This works-in fact, all methods of opening the form work except the OpenForm macro/VBA code, then it only malfunctions with the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike creating an 'Answer' while trying to solve, but felt it was easier to communicate more instructions / ideas. I will delete or update this answer based on solving the issue.

Please review all of my statements and confirm I have correctly stated what has been done.

Background: Opening a form form another form, using either a macro or VBA DoCmd.OpenForm causes error 'Runtime error 3000 and Reserved Error (-3087)'

Your normal VBA is as follows:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & [ID], acFormEdit, acNormal
```

You can run the above code from the Immediate Window and delete the 'Where Condition' (ID = ID), then the form will open ok.  Since [ID] is not in scope in the Immediate Window, you can't simply run the command with the 'Where' condition.

Is there ANY code in the form in the Open/Load/Resize/Activate/Current events?

Here is how I would proceed to debug:

1. Clone that form, save it as 'Form3000'.
2. Go to the code window, select ALL code and comment out.
3. Obtain a valid 'ID' for testing.
4. Create a subroutine in a new module as follows:

   ```
   Option Compare Database
   Option Explicit

   Sub Test3000()
   Dim MyID    As Long

   On Error GoTo Error_Trap
   MyID = InputBox("Enter a valid ID", "Enter Where COndition")
   'DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3000", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & [ID], acFormEdit, acNormal
   DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3000", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & MyID, acFormEdit, acNormal
   Exit Sub

   Error_Trap:
       Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
       MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
       Exit Sub
       Resume              ' If needed later...
       Resume Next
   End Sub
   ```
5. Execute the code, enter the valid ID.
6. What happens?
7. If it still fails, post the form property for Recordsource, Filter
8. If it works, then uncomment all the code in the form and post it in your question.

Based on what happens, we can try other options.